# How to activate Gedmo Ip_Traceable in a Symfony 2.7 project?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

On my Symfony 2.7 project, I use [StofDoctrineExtension‐Bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle). I have declared some entities. They use Timestampable, Loggable and Sluggable Gedmo behaviors. I installed it by reading [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html), on official Symfony documentation. When I'm creating some entity via Sonata Admin or my own use case, it works perfectly.

Now I want to use Gadmo IpTraceable behavior. I changed my entity declaration ORM YAML file by adding two properties `ipCreator` and `ipUdater` :

```
AppBundle\Entity\Vote:
  type: entity
  table: te_vote_vot
  id:
    id:
      type: bigint
      column: vot_id
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
      options:
        unsigned: true
        comment: Identifiant du classement
  fields:
    created:
      type: datetime
      nullable: false
      column: vot_creation
      options:
        comment: Creation date
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    ipCreator:
      type: string
      length: 45
      nullable: true
      column: vot_ip_creator
      options:
        comment: IP du voteur
      gedmo:
        ipTraceable:
          on: create
    ipUpdater:
      type: string
      length: 45
      nullable: true
      column: vot_ip_updater
      options:
        comment: IP du voteur en cas de modification
      gedmo:
        ipTraceable:
          on: update
    tracker:
      type: guid
      nullable: false
      column: vot_tracker
      options:
        comment: Tracker GGUID du voteur
    point:
      type: smallint
      nullable: false
      column: vot_point
      options:
        comment: Nombre de point que rapporte ce vote
  [...]
```

Timestampable behavior was called `created` property is well initialized, but `ipCreator` is not and stay `null` !

To activate Timestampable, I added some lines in `config.yml` file.

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: fr_FR
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
            sluggable: true
            loggable: true
```

I tried to add `iptraceable: true` , `ipTraceable: true` , `ip_traceable: true`. It didn't work iptraceable, ipTraceable, ip_traceable aren't configuration terms.

I had a look on [DependancyInjection/Configuration.php](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) source file.

```
$node
    ->useAttributeAsKey('id')
    ->prototype('array')
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('translatable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('timestampable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('blameable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('sluggable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('tree')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('loggable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('sortable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('softdeleteable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('uploadable')->defaultFalse()->end()
            ->scalarNode('reference_integrity')->defaultFalse()->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

No one of these words activated IPTraceable Behavior. ipCreator property stay null. I'm searching for a while, reading the doc, searching on the Web. And I don't find any solutions.

But [in documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/ip_traceable.md), I read that this line :

> IpTraceable is not yet available as Bundle for Symfony2, together with
>   all other extensions.

I'm not fluent in English, but I understood that I add to activate it "manually", not like a Bundle. But I don't know how to do it.

How can I use this IpTracable Doctrine Extensions ?

Comment: Maybe you could try with event subscriber, like in their documentation (even when ipTraceable in not in bundle for now, they have example of basic implementation in sf2 project) - [link](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/ip_traceable.md#example-of-implementation-in-symfony2)

Comment: Thanks for this link @IlyaYarkovets ! I didn't sawn this paragraph. I'll try this evening with event subscriber and I'll come back to forward the result.

Comment: Yes, it works with an event subscriber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1: With event subscriber

As @Ilya suggested, I tried with event subscriber like in [symfony documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/ip_traceable.md#example-of-implementation-in-symfony2).

But it was hard to configure the services, because I am using yml.

So here is a yaml version of the [services.xml](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/ip_traceable.md#configuration-for-servicesxml) file:

```
#app/config/services.yml
gedmo_doctrine_extensions.listener.ip_traceable:
    class: Gedmo\IpTraceable\IpTraceableListener
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader"]]

alterphp_doctrine_extensions.event_listener.ip_trace:
    class: %alterphp_doctrine_extensions.event_listener.ip_trace.class%
    scope: request
    arguments:
        - @gedmo_doctrine_extensions.listener.ip_traceable
        - @?request
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

## Method 2: Wait merge of Pull-Request #233

Since March 2014, there is a [pull-request #233](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/pull/233) wich add supports for for IpTraceable Gedmo extension. You can wait that the pull-request is merged with master. @stof does not seem to have time for this project, unfortunately. I don't know when it will be done.

## Method 3: With AlterPHP fork !

You can remove Stof/StofDoctrineExtensions from your composer.json and use [alterphp fork](https://github.com/alterphp/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/tree/iptraceable-listener)

Don't forget to call the iptraceable-listener branch!

You have to activate ip_traceable subscriber by editing your app/config/config.yml file

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            ip_traceable: true
```

For example, here is my config.yml file :

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: fr_FR
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
            sluggable: true
            loggable: true
            ip_traceable: true
```

I tried method 1 and 2, and both works perfectly. (but not together of course).

So take your pick ;)

Comment: In the method 1 with SF3 you need to add simple quote before the @ like : `'@gedmo_doctrine_extensions.listener.ip_traceable'`